# Error when trying to login a webpage using mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I want to log in to this japanese website using mechanize: https://fes.rakuten-bank.co.jp/MS/main/RbS?CurrentPageID=START&&COMMAND=LOGIN

this is the form information in the page:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import mechanize
import time

loginUrl="https://fes.rakuten-bank.co.jp/MS/main/RbS?CurrentPageID=START&&COMMAND=LOGIN"

#html読み込み(.albatross取得用)
br=mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders=[('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)')]

br.open(loginUrl)


br.select_form(nr=1)
br.form['LOGIN:USER_ID'] = 'xxxx'
br.form['LOGIN:LOGIN_PASSWORD'] = 'xxxx'
br.submit()
#br.click(name='LOGIN:_idJsp84')
```

And then I tried to print out the result:

```
for line in br.response():
    print line.decode("utf-8","ignore").encode("utf-8","ignore")
```

Result is:

```
<HTML>


<HEAD>


    <TITLE>Rakuten Bank</TITLE>


    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="/rb/fes/js/common/basicScripts.js" TYPE="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>


    <LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="/rb/fes/css/basicStyle.css" TYPE="text/css"/>


</HEAD>








<BODY ONLOAD="activateDisabledButton()">








<form id="_idJsp0" name="_idJsp0" method="post" action="/MS/main/fcs/rb/fes/jsp/common/error/InternalError.jsp" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">








<center>









































































<table width="100%">

<tr>

<td align="CENTER">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="740" class="marginlr01">

<tr>

<td>

<img src="/rb/fes/img/common/t.gif" alt="" height="18" width="1" /><br>



<img src="/rb/fes/img/common/header/logo_01.gif" alt="yVs" height="57" width="180" /><br>



<img src="/rb/fes/img/common/t.gif" alt="" height="18" width="1" /></td>

</tr>

</table>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

<tr>

<td bgcolor="#FFA600">

<img src="/rb/fes/img/common/t.gif" alt="" height="5" width="5" /></td>

</tr>

</table>

</td>

</tr>

</table>




</center>










<center>














































































































































<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

<tr align="center">

<td>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="740" class="marginlr01">

<tr>

<td>

<div class="margintop30">

</div>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="740">

<tr>

<td>

<img src="/rb/fes/img/common/parts_table04_top.gif" alt="" height="15" width="740" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="center" class="bgC03">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="720">

<tr>

<td valign="top" width="20">

<img src="/rb/fes/img/common/icn_alert.gif" alt="" height="15" width="16" /></td>

<td width="700">

<font class="errortxt">sȑ삪s܂B&lt;616029&gt;</font>

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>

<img src="/rb/fes/img/common/parts_table04_bottom.gif" alt="" height="15" width="740" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td align="center">

<br>



<input id="_idJsp0:_idJsp44" name="_idJsp0:_idJsp44" type="reset" value="" onclick="window.close();return false;clear__5FidJsp0();" onkeypress="window.close();return false" disabled="disabled" /></td>

</tr>

</table>

</td>

</tr>

</table>

</td>

</tr>

</table>




<br>






























<TABLE WIDTH="740" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" CLASS="copyright">


    <TR>


        <TD ALIGN="right">





            <SPAN id="pageNumber">CO0181</SPAN>


        </TD>


    </TR>


    <TR>


        <TD ALIGN="center">


            Copyright (c) 2001 Rakuten Bank, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.


        </TD>


    </TR>


    <TR>


        <TD HEIGHT="4" CLASS="bgC05"><IMG SRC="/rb/fes/img/common/t.gif" WIDTH="3" HEIGHT="3" ALT=""></TD>


    </TR>


</TABLE>








</center>










<input type="hidden" name="_idJsp0_SUBMIT" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="jsf_sequence" value="3" /><input type="hidden" name="_idJsp0:_link_hidden_" /><script type="text/javascript"><!--

function clear__5FidJsp0() {

  var f = document.forms['_idJsp0'];

  f.elements['_idJsp0:_link_hidden_'].value='';

  f.target='';

}

clear__5FidJsp0();

//--></script></form>








<!-- MYFACES JAVASCRIPT -->



</BODY>


</HTML>


>>>
```

It does not login. It returns the login page.
What is wrong here?

Comment: I don't know why the login fails, but the page seem to be encoded as Shift-JIS, not UTF8 as your printing code assumes.